# Wont display int declared in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
package assignment_3_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_3_1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //obtain package weight 1
    System.out.print("Enter the Package Weight (In Pounds): ");
    int packageWeight1 = input.nextInt();

    double WeightCalc1  = 5;
    double WeightCalc2  = 15;
    double WeightCalc3  = 34;
    double WeightCalc4  = 45;
    double WeightCalc5  = 60;
    double WeightCalc6  = 60;
    double priceA = 12;
    double priceB = 14;
    double priceC = 17;
    double priceD = 21;
    double priceE = 33;
    double priceF = 105;


    //if WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 12

   if (WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1)
   {
       System.out.println("The Base Charge is :  " + priceA);
       int basePrice = 12;
   }

   else
   {
        //if WeightCalc2 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 14
        if (WeightCalc2 >= packageWeight1)
        {
            System.out.println("The Base Charge is: " + priceB);
            int basePrice = 14;
        }

        else
        {
                //if WeightCalc3 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 17
                if (WeightCalc3 >= packageWeight1)
                {
                    System.out.println("The Base Charge is: " + priceC);
                    int basePrice = 17;
                }

                else
                {
                    //if weightCalc4 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 21
                    if (WeightCalc4 >= packageWeight1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The base charge is: " + priceD);
                        int basePrice = 21;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if weightCalc5 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 33
                        if (WeightCalc5 >= packageWeight1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("The base charge is: " + priceE );
                            int basePrice = 33;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if weightCalc6 < packageWeight1 the base charge is 105
                            if (WeightCalc6 < packageWeight1)
                            {
                                System.out.println("The base charge is: " + priceF);
                                int basePrice = 105;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Re-Run the Program");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        }


   }
   //obtain zipCode
   System.out.println("Enter your 5 Digit Zip Code: ");
   int zipCode = input.nextInt();

    double perc1 = 3999; 
    double perc2 = 5000;
    double perc3 = 5999;
    double perc4 = 7000;

    //if perc1 < basePrice < perc2
    if (perc1 < basePrice < perc2)
    {

    }

}
}
```

i declared an int inside of the if statement and when i started writing the bottom part after the large if statement i tried using basePrice the int i declared inside of the if statement i've tried changing the name of the int and using a double instead of an int and nothing will work not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: You should read this http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: Reason is your int within if will be visible within that if block only. If you want basePrice to be visible to your whole main method, then declare it out where you declared all your weight and price data.

Comment: Declare a `int basePrice=0;` out of all if and than do just a `basePrice=17,21...` inside the if statement.

Comment: learn Scope resolution Buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every `int basePrice` is declared in it's own scope and does not exist beyond that scope. You want to declare the `int` with all your doubles, like this:

```
double WeightCalc1  = 5;
double WeightCalc2  = 15;
double WeightCalc3  = 34;
double WeightCalc4  = 45;
double WeightCalc5  = 60;
double WeightCalc6  = 60;
double priceA = 12;
double priceB = 14;
double priceC = 17;
double priceD = 21;
double priceE = 33;
double priceF = 105;
// declare basePrice here
int basePrice;
```

Then instead of having these blocks:

```
   //if WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 12
   // base price only exists within these brackes

   if (WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1)
   {
    // base price only exists within these brackes
       System.out.println("The Base Charge is :  " + priceA);
       int basePrice = 12;
   }
```

You change to this:

```
   //if WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 12
   if (WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1)
   {
       System.out.println("The Base Charge is :  " + priceA);
       basePrice = 12;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In java the scope of a variable is local to a block. A block is generally code between {...}. If you need to use it out side the bold then you should declare it outside the block. See examples for details.

```
if(condition){
   int i=10;
}
```

You cannot use i outside the if.

If you wish to the you should do something like

```
int i =0;
if(condition)
{
   i=10;
}
```

Now you can use it outside the if.

Answer (score 0):

Variable's scope is limited to that if only.

You can not access it outside that if condition.

You can declare it global to access it in another if.

**Update**

```
int basePrice = 0;  // declare
```

and after that assign values in other if conditions.

```
 if (WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1)
   {
       System.out.println("The Base Charge is :  " + priceA);
      // int basePrice = 12;  //--not like this
      basePrice = 12;   // assign
   }
```

Comment: thank you for the help is there any way i can make it permanent so i can use it out of the if statement

Comment: @GarrettCarder Initialize the variable outside the if statement to make it able to be accessed outside the if. You then just set the value inside the if.

Comment: how do i declare it global

Comment: @GarrettCarder- Keep it out side first if..it will be accessible in next if..see updated answer..

Answer (score 0):

Declare the int `basePrice` at the beginning (with packageWeight1 for example), initialize it to some value (0?) then change all the `int basePrice = ...` to `basePrice = ...`

Once the if statement is finished executing any values declared inside are lost.

Answer (score 0):

`basePrice` is defined within the scope of the `if` statements. Move this outside the scope of the statement

```
int basePrice = 12;

if (weightCalc1 >= packageWeight1) {
  ...
```

Also the statement

```
if (perc1 < basePrice < perc2) {
```

won't compile. Perhaps you meant

```
if (perc1 < basePrice && basePrice < perc2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

declare it outside the if because u are restricting its scope to that if only

```
package assignment_3_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_3_1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //obtain package weight 1
    System.out.print("Enter the Package Weight (In Pounds): ");
    int packageWeight1 = input.nextInt();

    double WeightCalc1  = 5;
    double WeightCalc2  = 15;
    double WeightCalc3  = 34;
    double WeightCalc4  = 45;
    double WeightCalc5  = 60;
    double WeightCalc6  = 60;
    double priceA = 12;
    double priceB = 14;
    double priceC = 17;
    double priceD = 21;
    double priceE = 33;
    double priceF = 105;
       int basePrice = 12; // declare it here and it will work
    //if WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1 the base charge is 12

   if (WeightCalc1 >= packageWeight1)
   {
       System.out.println("The Base Charge is :  " + priceA);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code having a problem with `basePrice`. You are declaring `basePrice` inside `if` & `else` and you are using it outside it. Try declaring as global variable inside `main` method so that you can access from anywhere in `main`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int basePrice = 0;

    // Your rest of code will be here ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basePrice has to be declared at the beginning of the main

Here is some refactoring :

```
private static Integer checkWeight(int packageWeight, int weightCalc, int price)
{
    if (weightCalc >= packageWeight)
    {
        System.out.println("The Base Charge is: " + price);
        return price;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //obtain package weight 1
    System.out.print("Enter the Package Weight (In Pounds): ");
    int packageWeight1 = input.nextInt();

    int[] weightCalcs = {5, 15, 34, 45, 60, 60};
    int[] prices = {12, 14, 17, 21, 33, 105};

    Integer basePrice = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < weightCalcs.length; i++)
    {
        if ((basePrice = checkWeight(packageWeight1, weightCalcs[i], prices[i])) != null)
        {
            // price found !
            break;
        }
    }

    if (basePrice != null)
    {
       //obtain zipCode
       System.out.println("Enter your 5 Digit Zip Code: ");
       int zipCode = input.nextInt();

        double perc1 = 3999; 
        double perc2 = 5000;
        double perc3 = 5999;
        double perc4 = 7000;

        // TODO using basePrice for the next intructions
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Re-Run the Program");
    }
}
```